# Javascript validation focus

Tags: javascript, validation, focus

I am writing a validation script for an HTML form.  The script makes a list of errors appear at the top of the document, so that the user can see (and correct) them all at once.  I'd like the focus to move to that error list when the document reloads after the validation script runs, but this isn't working, and heaven help me I can't see why.  Any tips would be very much appreciated.  Thank you!

Here is the JS

```
function validate(survey) {
    var error=document.createElement("text");
    error.innerHTML=" ";

    var x=document.survey.member_email.value;
    if (x==null || x=="")  {
        error.innerHTML+="<li>Please enter an email address</li>" 
        var vp=document.getElementById("validate_place");
        vp.appendChild(error);
        vp.focus( );      //  Here is the focus command   -->//
        return false;
        } 
    return true;
}
```

And here are the validation lines in HTML:

```
<form action="survey_processing.php" method="post"  onsubmit="return validate(this);"  name="survey" id="survey" >

<div id="validate_place" > </div>  <!--- empty div to insert validation correction info if needed -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the `tabindex` attribute of the div to -1 you enable the ability to pass focus to it programatically. (scroll down to tabindex at the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Global_attributes) for more details)

```
<div id="validate_place" tabindex="-1"> </div>
```

Comment: This is the first I'm hearing about tabindex, and it seems fantastic.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @rebaelliott It is an incredibly useful tool especially when it comes to deisgning accesible websites.

Comment: That is also news to me. How cross browser is that?

Comment: @mplungjan [Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/tabindex#compatibilitysection) is the only place i can find an actual compatability table, but its not a new thing its behaved this way for some time but its behaviour was codified as part of the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/editing.html#attr-tabindex).

Comment: @Simon West Yes to accessibility.  I'm thinking of adding a tabindex attribute to all my divs.  Pretty tiny task for a pretty big gain.  Thanks again for the info.

Answer (score 1):

vp is a div. there is no focus available. (Actually it seems there is with a negative tabindex thanks Simon)

You can scroll to the error using

```
vp.scrollIntoView();
```

You can focus a form field so if you assign the field to x imstead ofnits value you can use `x.value` and `x.focus()`

Comment: Thank you, @mplungjan!  I am new to this, as you can tell . . . scrollIntoView( ) worked perfectly.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can't accept for another minute.  I think there is a 5-minute delay, because I tried to accept immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The 'x' variable contains the value of "member_email" field. If you want to use `x.focus();`, you should add:

```
var x = document.survey.member_email;
```

Then use: `x.value` to check 'x'.